# How to implement VARIANT in Protobuf

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

As part of my protobuf protocol I require the ability to send data of a dynamic type, a little bit like [VARIANT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type). Roughly I require the data to be an integer, string, boolean or "other" where "other" (e.g. `DateTime`) is serialized as a string. I need to be able to use these as a single field and in lists in a number of different locations in the protocol.

**How can this best be implemented while keeping message size minimal and performance optimal?**

I'm using protobuf-net with C#.

**EDIT:**
I've posted a proposed answer below which uses what I think is the minimum of memory required.

**EDIT2:**
Created a github.com project at http://github.com/pvginkel/ProtoVariant with a complete implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jon's multiple optionals covers the simplest setup, especially if you need cross-platform support. On the .NET side (to ensure you don't serialize unnecessary values), simply return `null` from any property that isn't a match, for example:

```
public object Value { get;set;}
[ProtoMember(1)]
public int? ValueInt32 {
    get { return (Value is int) ? (int)Value : (int?)null; }
    set { Value = value; }
}
[ProtoMember(2)]
public string ValueString {
    get { return (Value is string) ? (string)Value : null; }
    set { Value = value; }
}
// etc
```

You can also do the same using the `bool ShouldSerialize*()` pattern if you don't like the nulls.

Wrap that up in a `class` and you should be fine to use that at either the field level or list level. You mention optimal performance; the only additional thing I can suggest there is to perhaps consider treating as a "group" rather than "submessage", as this is easier to encode (and just as easy to decode, as long as you expect the data). To do that, use the `Grouped` data-format, via `[ProtoMember]`, i.e.

```
[ProtoMember(12, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
public MyVariant Foo {get;set;}
```

However, the difference here can be minimal - but it avoids some back-tracking in the output stream to fix the lengths. Either way, in terms of *overheads* a "submessage" will take at least 2 bytes; "at least one" for the field-header (perhaps taking more if the `12` is actually `1234567`) - and "at least one" for the length, which gets bigger for longer messages. A group takes 2 x the field-header, so if you use low field-numbers this will be 2 bytes regardless of the length of the encapsulated data (it could be 5MB of binary).

A separate trick, useful for more complex scenarios but not as interoperable, is generic inheritance, i.e. an abstract base class that has `ConcreteType<int>`, `ConcreteType<string>` etc listed as subtypes - this, however, takes an extra 2 bytes (typically), so is not as frugal.

Taking *another* step further away from the core spec, if you *genuinely can't tell* what types you need to support, and don't need interoperability - there is some support for including (optimized) type information in the data; see the `DynamicType` option on `ProtoMember` - this takes more space than the other two options.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a message like this:

```
message Variant {
    optional string string_value = 1;
    optional int32 int32_value = 2;
    optional int64 int64_value = 3;
    optional string other_value = 4;
    // etc
}
```

Then write a helper class - and possibly extension methods - to ensure that you only ever set *one* field in the variant.

You could optionally include a separate enum value to specify which field is set (to make it more like a tagged union) but the ability to check the optional fields just means the data is already there. It depends on whether you want the speed of finding the right field (in which case add the discriminator) or the space efficiency of *only* including the data itself (in which case don't add the discriminator).

That's a *general* Protocol Buffer approach. There may be something more protobuf-net specific, of course.

Comment: I'd probably need a discriminator, if only for the serialized string. I'm concerned about the overhead. This means I need 2 extra bytes for the field types and tags and 1 byte for the actual discriminator value. For a simple integer this is 400% of the original. I was hoping for something more efficient :). Do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: By the way; I am open to switching implementations if protobuf-csharp-port gives me a more space efficient option. Nothing's written in stone.

Comment: @Pieter: Don't forget that the simple integer may well map down to a single byte if it's small... giving you 4 bytes even with all that extra information. Basically discriminated unions *will* have extra overhead, and there's nothing in Protocol Buffers to special-case them. It would probably be possible to have a wire format which "knew" that exactly one field would be filled, and put that in with the tag somewhere... but there's nothing in the normal wire format for that.

Comment: @Pieter: protobuf-csharp-port *definitely* doesn't have any special-case support for this. It generates partial classes, so you can add extra functionality that way, but that's all. (protobuf-net may generate partial classes too; I don't know.)

Comment: @Pieter the space is pretty much determined in advance by the spec ;p (unless we allow for subnormnal forms)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the only option that would actually save space then is to encode it myself. If I would make the field `byte[]` and serialize the data myself I could get away with 1 byte for the `byte[]` length and 1 byte for the discriminator which saves me, yes, 1 byte. Don't know if it's worth it though. Thanks to you all for your help.

Comment: Found a way to squeeze out those last two bytes. Comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Asking questions always helps me think. I found a way to get the number of bytes used for transfer to a bare minimum.

What I've done here is make use of optional properties. Say I want to send an int32. When the value isn't zero, I can just check a property on the message for whether it has a value. Otherwise, I set a type to INT32_ZERO. This way I can correctly store and reconstruct the value. The example below has this implementation for a number of types.

The .proto file:

```
message Variant {
    optional VariantType type = 1 [default = AUTO];
    optional int32 value_int32 = 2;
    optional int64 value_int64 = 3;
    optional float value_float = 4;
    optional double value_double = 5;
    optional string value_string = 6;
    optional bytes value_bytes = 7;
    optional string value_decimal = 8;
    optional string value_datetime = 9;
}

enum VariantType {
    AUTO = 0;
    BOOL_FALSE = 1;
    BOOL_TRUE = 2;
    INT32_ZERO = 3;
    INT64_ZERO = 4;
    FLOAT_ZERO = 5;
    DOUBLE_ZERO = 6;
    NULL = 7;
}
```

And accompanying partial .cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    partial class Variant
    {
        public static Variant Create(object value)
        {
            var result = new Variant();

            if (value == null)
                result.Type = VariantType.NULL;
            else if (value is string)
                result.ValueString = (string)value;
            else if (value is byte[])
                result.ValueBytes = (byte[])value;
            else if (value is bool)
                result.Type = (bool)value ? VariantType.BOOLTRUE : VariantType.BOOLFALSE;
            else if (value is float)
            {
                if ((float)value == 0f)
                    result.Type = VariantType.FLOATZERO;
                else
                    result.ValueFloat = (float)value;
            }
            else if (value is double)
            {
                if ((double)value == 0d)
                    result.Type = VariantType.DOUBLEZERO;
                else
                    result.ValueDouble = (double)value;
            }
            else if (value is decimal)
                result.ValueDecimal = ((decimal)value).ToString("r", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            else if (value is DateTime)
                result.ValueDatetime = ((DateTime)value).ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Cannot store data type {0} in Variant", value.GetType().FullName), "value");

            return result;
        }

        public object Value
        {
            get
            {
                switch (Type)
                {
                    case VariantType.BOOLFALSE:
                        return false;

                    case VariantType.BOOLTRUE:
                        return true;

                    case VariantType.NULL:
                        return null;

                    case VariantType.DOUBLEZERO:
                        return 0d;

                    case VariantType.FLOATZERO:
                        return 0f;

                    case VariantType.INT32ZERO:
                        return 0;

                    case VariantType.INT64ZERO:
                        return (long)0;

                    default:
                        if (ValueInt32 != 0)
                            return ValueInt32;
                        if (ValueInt64 != 0)
                            return ValueInt64;
                        if (ValueFloat != 0f)
                            return ValueFloat;
                        if (ValueDouble != 0d)
                            return ValueDouble;
                        if (ValueString != null)
                            return ValueString;
                        if (ValueBytes != null)
                            return ValueBytes;
                        if (ValueDecimal != null)
                            return Decimal.Parse(ValueDecimal, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        if (ValueDatetime != null)
                            return DateTime.Parse(ValueDatetime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Further comments from @Marc Gravell have improved the implementation significantly. See the Git repository for a complete implementation of this concept.

Comment: How many fields do you serilize? Just the type? Or the type and the value?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but Type is left at AUTO (optional so not serialized) when e.g. ValueInt32 is set to 1. I've created a complete implementation of this at https://github.com/pvginkel/ProtoVariant.git including unit tests and such.

Comment: @Pieter k; I just wanted to make sure you weren't sending unnecessary dat5. I'm not sure why you are calling out the zeros, though - it takes exactly the same space to serialize a zero integer as it does to serialize the enum saying "I'm a zero integer"... likewise the bools and the long; the `double` and `float` are shorter as an enum, agreed.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - What I understand from the documentation was that the trigger to not serialize optional fields is whether it has its default value. That's the reason I call out the zeros. I though this was the only way to actually return a 0f or a 0L.

Comment: @Pieter ah, right; as I tried to explain in my answer you can be more fine-grained than that (plus these implicit defaults are a constant cause of confusion - I might make a toggle in v2 to kill them). There are a *number* of ways to do that; nullable values (`int?`) is one-such, but another is the `bool ShouldSerialize*()` pattern (borrowed from core .NET) - i.e. if you have `int ValueInt {...}` and `bool ShouldSerializeValueInt() { /* true to serialize, false not to */ }` it will behave as you prefer.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - Very very cool. I'll integrate this in the project. Thank you very much. I've changed the answer to you because I now understand that this is what you meant whole the time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually protobuf doesn't support any kind of `VARIANT` types.
You can try to play around using Unions, see more details [here](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/techniques.html#union)
The main idea is to define message wrapper with all existing message types as optional field, and by using `union` just specify which type of this concrete message it is.
See example by following the link above.

Comment: I know I'd probably need to go for something like that. However, what I'm looking for is something that performs and is space efficient. See answer by Jon Skeet and my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I use ProtoInclude with an abstract base type and subclasses to get the type and single value statically set. Here's the start of what that could look like for Variant:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Integer))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(String))]
public abstract class Variant
{
    [ProtoContract]
    public sealed class Integer
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Value;
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public sealed class String
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var foo = new Variant.String { Value = "Bar" };
var baz = new Variant.Integer { Value = 10 };
```

This answer gives takes a bit more space as it encodes the length of the ProtoInclude'd class instance (e.g. 1 byte for int and under < 125 byte strings). I am willing to live with this for the benefit of controlling the type statically.